# Android webview not showing

Tags: android, webview

I have created a webview but it is not showing when I run the app. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code. This is where I load the webview and add a url:

```
_webView = (WebView) LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.clubdir, null);

_webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
_webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
_webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
_webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + Postcode + "&ui=maps");

adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addView(ImageView);
adapter.addView(header);
adapter.addView(fixturesView);
adapter.addView(header2);
adapter.addView(resultsView);
adapter.addView(clubinfo);
adapter.addView(ClubInfo);
adapter.addView(clubdir);
adapter.addView(_webView);
adapter.addView(moreinfo);
adapter.addView(MoreInfo); 
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the layout that I am inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
</WebView>
```

Comment: Have you given the `Internet` permission?

Comment: yes i have given internet permission

Comment: What's your layout `clubdir` contains only webView or anyother? and also, Try to use `yourActivity.this` for inflating the `WebView` instead of `getBaseContext()`

Comment: Note the almost duplicate lines with a uppercase change in the argument's name for  
    adapter.addView(clubinfo); and 
    adapter.addView(ClubInfo);
as well as
adapter.addView(moreinfo);
adapter.addView(MoreInfo);

Answer (score 4):

instead of this try this only simple thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
</WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity:

```
    WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Pizza,texas&ui=maps");
```

that's it.try hope this will help you.if it works than proceed with adding other things

Comment: hi that worked but it shows the entire web page is there a way to just show the map

Comment: i just passed the url of home page.whatever u want to see pass url inside it.it will help you.

Comment: @LukeBatley Then, you better try the `MapView` with your needed size with it.

Comment: you must have to pass latitude and longitude in url